# Lucene sort by date descending

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to sort a Lucene search firstly by a boolean field and then by a datetime. I have this:

```
SortField[] sortFields = new SortField[]
  { 
    new SortField(LuceneMedia.IndexFields.IsPrivate, SortField.STRING, true),
    new SortField(LuceneMedia.IndexFields.DateAdded, SortField.STRING, true)
  };
Sort sort = new Sort(sortFields);
```

The boolean field is being sorted correct, but the date seems a bit random.

```
SortField[] sortFields = new SortField[]
  { 
    new SortField(LuceneMedia.IndexFields.IsPrivate, SortField.STRING, true),
    new SortField(LuceneMedia.IndexFields.DateAdded, SortField.LONG, true)
  };
Sort sort = new Sort(sortFields);
```

But now it seems to ignore the date and is ordering by the document title, which isn't part of the sort at all.

Comment: How are you indexing your dates?  Strings or Longs are each possibilities, it just depends on how you indexed them.

Comment: Hi, Ive chnaged the way they were indexed to yyyymmddhhmmss so that they can be sorted. Thanks for answer

Comment: The code you provided should work... The third parameter of the method `SortField()` when set to `true` should do it.